# Setting extent of Geostatistical Layer for further Export to Grid using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, geostatistical-analyst

I am writing a script to create JPEG interpolational maps using Geostatistical layer (calculated on RadialBasisFunctions).

I have a point-feature file which I use to create this GA Layer. There's a huge block with cycle, but here's the trouble inside:

```
    arcpy.RadialBasisFunctions_ga(inPointFeatures, zField, outLayer, outRaster, cellSize, searchNeighbourhood, rbf, smallscaleParam)
    arcpy.GALayerToGrid_ga (outLayer, "gs_raster")
    ......
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("gs_raster")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, addLayer, "TOP")
```

Well, it works, but I need (as you can see on the screenshot) the extent of this GA raster to be the same as this tiny red boundary line shapefile (So I would use it after in ExtractbyMask)

[image]

I just don't know how to apply an extent to this raster.

How can I implement such a setting of extent here in the script?

Comment: Have you tried [Output Extent](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/output-extent.htm) Environment setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this:

```
File_YouWant_ToGetExtent_From = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
....
arcpy.env.extent = File_YouWant_ToGetExtent_From
```